# Trying to start Stopwatch based off of old split saved in .txt file

Tags: vb.net

The closest I have gotten is to get the last line in the .txt file (there are a bunch of splits saved), and then add that to the current elapsed time, and then display THAT in the label box:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
    Dim lastline As String

    lastline = lines(lines.Length - 1)

    Dim elapsed As TimeSpan = Me.stopwatch.Elapsed
    Dim pastHours As String
    pastHours = lastline.Substring(0, 2)
    Dim currentHours As Double = elapsed.Hours + pastHours

    Dim pastMinutes As String
    pastMinutes = lastline.Substring(3, 2)
    Dim currentMinutes As Double = elapsed.Minutes + pastMinutes

    Dim pastSeconds As String
    pastSeconds = lastline.Substring(6, 2)
    Dim currentSeconds As Double = elapsed.Seconds + pastSeconds

    Dim pastMilliseconds As String
    pastMilliseconds = lastline.Substring(9, 3)
    Dim currentMilliseconds As Double = elapsed.Milliseconds + pastMilliseconds

    Label1.Text = Format(currentHours, "00") & ":" & Format(currentMinutes, "00") & ":" & Format(currentSeconds, "00") & "." & (currentMilliseconds)
End Sub
```

The only problem with that, is that instead of having 1000 milliseconds in a second, 60 seconds in a minute, etc, it will go up to 60 PLUS whatever that last split has saved. For example, if the last split saved was 34 seconds, it will take until a displayed amount of 94 seconds before it ticks up a minute, and even then it will start the seconds over at 34 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the text that is being split.

Comment: Also, it could be helpful to pause execution, hover the mouse over each variable after it has been updated and post those values next to their corresponding  variables in your question.

Comment: Here is the text I would be splitting up:
00:08:28.243
It successfully splits that up into each individual variable, and successfully adds the current elapsed time to the time that it pulls in from the .txt file, the only problem is that it then ends up with a ridiculous time like "00:08:114.1242"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `TimeSpan` values to each other. In your case, you could do:

```
Dim pastElapsed As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, pastHours, pastMinutes, pastSeconds, pastMilliseconds)
Dim currentElapsed As TimeSpan = elapsed + pastElapsed
Dim formatted As String = Format(currentElapsed.Hours, "00") & ":" & Format(currentElapsed.Minutes, "00") & ":" & Format(currentElapsed.Seconds, "00") & "." & Format(currentElapsed.Milliseconds, "000")
Label1.Text = formatted
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I had no clue that was a thing! That cleared it right up!